# Fabric android: redirection to login screen

Tags: android, twitter, google-fabric

I want to use the twitter share functionality from my android application. Using Fabric, I want to redirect the user to the twitter login screen (if he is not logged in) of the twitter application if it's installed or to the browser.  I searched about that I found some informations in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629838/twitter-fabric-login-for-android) but I don’t know how can I do what I want.

Can anyone help me please or guide me on what have I to do?

Comment: refer my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648384/android-fabric-twitter-share-listener/39264078#39264078. it uses rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Fabric plugin properly and follow the steps there

And then add this code in your java inside the desired scope:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
 private void setuptwlogin() {
 loginButton=(TwitterLoginButton)findViewById(R.id.xtwlogin);
 loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
 @Override
 public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
 Log.w("myApp", result.data.toString());
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"succueess",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 composetweet();
 }
 @Override
 public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 });
 }
 private void composetweet() {
 TweetComposer.Builder builder=new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
.text("This is made by saptak das")
 .image(Uri.parse("http://www.thehealthsync.com/knowhow_res/1.jpg"));
 builder.show();
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use the twitter button, will this code work without this: loginButton=(TwitterLoginButton)findViewById(R.id.xtwlogin); ?